# Adding bridge for LXC breaks NAT/DNS

Tags: networking, juju, dns, lxc, nat

I am having a issue with a small home server. This server operates as a DNS/DHCP/NAT. I am also trying to add a few LXC instances with JUJU however I am running into a issue with the bridge. When I apply the configuration and restart the networking service it works. However if the server is ever restarted the NAT breaks.

Here is my /etc/networking

```
*# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto lxcbr0

iface lxcbr0 inet static
        address 10.0.3.1
        broadcast 10.0.3.255
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        bridge_ports eth1
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Let me know if you need any other information

Comment: For clarification, is the DHCP/DNS/NAT specifically for the lxc containers or the remainder of your network? Which interfaces is it bound to? How does it 'break'?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have done read manual here: [LXC](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html).

Also, take a look on discussion here:  [lxcbr0 default does not work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2137446) .